# Grouped time difference when a condition is met

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am working with structured log data structured as the following ([here](https://pastebin.com/raw/qrqTMrGa) a pastebin snippet of mock data for easy tinkering):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("https://pastebin.com/raw/qrqTMrGa")
print(df)

     id        date  info_a_cnt  info_b_cnt  has_err
0   123  2020-01-01         123          32        0
1   123  2020-01-02           2          43        0
2   123  2020-01-03          43           4        1
3   123  2020-01-04          43           4        0
4   123  2020-01-05          43           4        0
5   123  2020-01-06          43           4        0
6   123  2020-01-07          43           4        1
7   123  2020-01-08          43           4        0
8   232  2020-01-04          56           4        0
9   232  2020-01-05          97           1        0
10  232  2020-01-06          23          74        0
11  232  2020-01-07          91          85        1
12  232  2020-01-08          91          85        0
13  232  2020-01-09          91          85        0
14  232  2020-01-10          91          85        1
```

Variables are pretty straightforward:

- `id`: the id of the observed machine
- `date`: observation date
- `info_a_cnt`: counts of a specific kind of info event
- `info_b_cnt`: same as above for a different event type
- `has_err`: whether or not the machine logged any errors

Now, I'd like to group the dataframe by `id` to create a variable storing the number of days left before an error event. The desired dataframe should look like:

```py
     id        date  info_a_cnt  info_b_cnt  has_err  days_to_err
0   123  2020-01-01         123          32        0            2
1   123  2020-01-02           2          43        0            1
2   123  2020-01-03          43           4        1            0
3   123  2020-01-04          43           4        0            3
4   123  2020-01-05          43           4        0            2
5   123  2020-01-06          43           4        0            1
6   123  2020-01-07          43           4        1            0
7   232  2020-01-04          56           4        0            3
8   232  2020-01-05          97           1        0            2
9   232  2020-01-06          23          74        0            1
10  232  2020-01-07          91          85        1            0
11  232  2020-01-08          91          85        0            2
12  232  2020-01-09          91          85        0            1
13  232  2020-01-10          91          85        1            0
```

I am having an hard time figuring out the correct implementation with the right grouping functions.

### Edit:

All the answers below work really well when dealing with dates with a daily granularity. I am wondering how to adapt @jezrael solution below to a dataframe containing timestamps (logs will be batched with **15** minutes interval):

[df](https://pastebin.com/raw/YZukAhBz):

```
df = pd.read_csv("https://pastebin.com/raw/YZukAhBz")
print(df)

     id                 date  info_a_cnt  info_b_cnt  has_err
0   123  2020-01-01 12:00:00         123          32        0
1   123  2020-01-01 12:15:00           2          43        0
2   123  2020-01-01 12:30:00          43           4        1
3   123  2020-01-01 12:45:00          43           4        0
4   123  2020-01-01 13:00:00          43           4        0
5   123  2020-01-01 13:15:00          43           4        0
6   123  2020-01-01 13:30:00          43           4        1
7   123  2020-01-01 13:45:00          43           4        0
8   232  2020-01-04 17:00:00          56           4        0
9   232  2020-01-05 17:15:00          97           1        0
10  232  2020-01-06 17:30:00          23          74        0
11  232  2020-01-07 17:45:00          91          85        1
12  232  2020-01-08 18:00:00          91          85        0
13  232  2020-01-09 18:15:00          91          85        0
14  232  2020-01-10 18:30:00          91          85        1
```

I am wondering how to adapt @jezrael answer in order to land on something like:

```py
     id                 date  info_a_cnt  info_b_cnt  has_err  mins_to_err
0   123  2020-01-01 12:00:00         123          32        0           30
1   123  2020-01-01 12:15:00           2          43        0           15
2   123  2020-01-01 12:30:00          43           4        1            0
3   123  2020-01-01 12:45:00          43           4        0           45
4   123  2020-01-01 13:00:00          43           4        0           30
5   123  2020-01-01 13:15:00          43           4        0           15
6   123  2020-01-01 13:30:00          43           4        1            0
7   123  2020-01-01 13:45:00          43           4        0           60
8   232  2020-01-04 17:00:00          56           4        0           45
9   232  2020-01-05 17:15:00          97           1        0           30
10  232  2020-01-06 17:30:00          23          74        0           15
11  232  2020-01-07 17:45:00          91          85        1            0
12  232  2020-01-08 18:00:00          91          85        0           30
13  232  2020-01-09 18:15:00          91          85        0           15
14  232  2020-01-10 18:30:00          91          85        1            0
```

Comment: That was an error indeed, good catch. Just edited the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with `ascending=False` by column `id` and helper Series with [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) but form back - so added indexing by [`Series.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iloc.html):

```
g = f['has_err'].iloc[::-1].cumsum().iloc[::-1]
df['days_to_err'] = df.groupby(['id', g])['has_err'].cumcount(ascending=False)
print(df)
     id        date  info_a_cnt  info_b_cnt  has_err  days_to_err
0   123  2020-01-01         123          32        0            2
1   123  2020-01-02           2          43        0            1
2   123  2020-01-03          43           4        1            0
3   123  2020-01-04          43           4        0            3
4   123  2020-01-05          43           4        0            2
5   123  2020-01-06          43           4        0            1
6   123  2020-01-07          43           4        1            0
7   123  2020-01-08          43           4        0            0
8   232  2020-01-04          56           4        0            3
9   232  2020-01-05          97           1        0            2
10  232  2020-01-06          23          74        0            1
11  232  2020-01-07          91          85        1            0
12  232  2020-01-08          91          85        0            2
13  232  2020-01-09          91          85        0            1
14  232  2020-01-10          91          85        1            0
```

EDIT: For count cumulative sum of differencies of dates use custom lambda function with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['days_to_err'] = (df.groupby(['id', df['has_err'].iloc[::-1].cumsum()])['date']
                       .transform(lambda x: x.diff().dt.days.cumsum())
                       .fillna(0)
                       .to_numpy()[::-1])
print(df)
     id       date  info_a_cnt  info_b_cnt  has_err  days_to_err
0   123 2020-01-01         123          32        0          2.0
1   123 2020-01-02           2          43        0          1.0
2   123 2020-01-03          43           4        1          0.0
3   123 2020-01-04          43           4        0          3.0
4   123 2020-01-05          43           4        0          2.0
5   123 2020-01-06          43           4        0          1.0
6   123 2020-01-07          43           4        1          0.0
7   123 2020-01-08          43           4        0          0.0
8   232 2020-01-04          56           4        0          3.0
9   232 2020-01-05          97           1        0          2.0
10  232 2020-01-06          23          74        0          1.0
11  232 2020-01-07          91          85        1          0.0
12  232 2020-01-08          91          85        0          2.0
13  232 2020-01-09          91          85        0          1.0
14  232 2020-01-10          91          85        1          0.0
```

EDIT1: Use [`Series.dt.total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) with divide by `60`:

```
#some data sample cleaning
df = pd.read_csv("https://pastebin.com/raw/YZukAhBz", parse_dates=['date'])
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(month=1, day=1))
print(df)

df['days_to_err'] = (df.groupby(['id', df['has_err'].iloc[::-1].cumsum()])['date']
                       .transform(lambda x: x.diff().dt.total_seconds().div(60).cumsum())
                       .fillna(0)
                       .to_numpy()[::-1])
print(df)


     id                date  info_a_cnt  info_b_cnt  has_err  days_to_err
0   123 2020-01-01 12:00:00         123          32        0         30.0
1   123 2020-01-01 12:15:00           2          43        0         15.0
2   123 2020-01-01 12:30:00          43           4        1          0.0
3   123 2020-01-01 12:45:00          43           4        0         45.0
4   123 2020-01-01 13:00:00          43           4        0         30.0
5   123 2020-01-01 13:15:00          43           4        0         15.0
6   123 2020-01-01 13:30:00          43           4        1          0.0
7   123 2020-01-01 13:45:00          43           4        0          0.0
8   232 2020-01-01 17:00:00          56           4        0         45.0
9   232 2020-01-01 17:15:00          97           1        0         30.0
10  232 2020-01-01 17:30:00          23          74        0         15.0
11  232 2020-01-01 17:45:00          91          85        1          0.0
12  232 2020-01-01 18:00:00          91          85        0         30.0
13  232 2020-01-01 18:15:00          91          85        0         15.0
14  232 2020-01-01 18:30:00          91          85        1          0.0
```

Comment: This worked like a charm but it uses a row count. Would there be any way to use an actual time difference (using the `date` column)? I am wondering how this could be adapted when dealing with more granular timestamps.

Comment: [:: - 1] twice is not necessary here

Comment: @ansev - ya, in your solution is second `[::-1]` do pandas, because not match index order, what is not so safe. So add it is better.

Comment: I think it is safe

Comment: @ansev - OK, no problem with it. ;) Happy coding

Comment: @jezrael Surprisingly your solution doesn't behave too well when having more granular timestamps, updated my question accordingly. Sorry for the mishap.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df2 = df[::-1]
df['days_to_err'] = df2.groupby(['id', df2['has_err'].eq(1).cumsum()]).cumcount()

     id        date  info_a_cnt  info_b_cnt  has_err  days_to_err
0   123  2020-01-01         123          32        0            2
1   123  2020-01-02           2          43        0            1
2   123  2020-01-03          43           4        1            0
3   123  2020-01-04          43           4        0            3
4   123  2020-01-05          43           4        0            2
5   123  2020-01-06          43           4        0            1
6   123  2020-01-07          43           4        1            0
7   123  2020-01-08          43           4        0            0
8   232  2020-01-04          56           4        0            3
9   232  2020-01-05          97           1        0            2
10  232  2020-01-06          23          74        0            1
11  232  2020-01-07          91          85        1            0
12  232  2020-01-08          91          85        0            2
13  232  2020-01-09          91          85        0            1
14  232  2020-01-10          91          85        1            0
```